# Recycler View only showing the first view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a Recycler View but the issue is that it only displays the first item. It is not the issue of the list that I am passing because it shows 2 items in the logcat which is correct.

The Logcat:

```
D/TAGG LIST: [com.avalonglobalresearch.creatives.ImageUploadInfo@45bea08, com.avalonglobalresearch.creatives.ImageUploadInfo@6a145a1]
```

So the issue most probably is with the adapter.
Here is the adapter code:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter2  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

Context context2;
List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;


public RecyclerViewAdapter2(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context2 = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items2, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(UploadInfo.getImageURL());
    Log.d("TAGGG" , ""+uri);
    //holder.videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public VideoView videoView;
    public TextView imageNameTextView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        videoView = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView2);

        imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    }
}
}
```

This is the class where I want to inflate the RecyclerView.

```
public class Photography extends AppCompatActivity {

private SlidrInterface slidr;
// Creating DatabaseReference.
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

// Creating RecyclerView.
RecyclerView recyclerView;

// Creating RecyclerView.Adapter.
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;

// Creating Progress dialog
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Creating List of ImageUploadInfo class.
List<ImageUploadInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photography);

    // Assign id to RecyclerView.
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    // Setting RecyclerView size true.
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Setting RecyclerView layout as LinearLayout.
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Photography.this));

    // Assign activity this to progress dialog.
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Photography.this);

    // Setting up message in Progress dialog.
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Videos From Firebase.");

    // Showing progress dialog.
    progressDialog.show();

    slidr = Slidr.attach(this);

    // Setting up Firebase image upload folder path in databaseReference.
    // The path is already defined in MainActivity.
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All_Uploads/Design/Videos/" );

    // Adding Add Value Event Listener to databaseReference.
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = postSnapshot.getValue(ImageUploadInfo.class);

                list.add(imageUploadInfo);
                Log.d("TAGG LIST" , ""+list.toString());
            }

            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter2(getApplicationContext(), list);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Hiding the progress dialog.
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            // Hiding the progress dialog.
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Please show me where I am going wrong.

Comment: check if your custom row height is set to **match_parent**

Comment: Check the height attribute of the parent view in your `items2` layout.